# Пытаюсь обновить Laravel с 8 до 9 версии, но не могу понять что от меня composer хочет. Может кто подсказать?

Tags: php, laravel, composer

В общем, поменял в `composer.json` все что нужно для обновления Laravel до 9 версии

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
```

Но после выполнения команды `php composer.phar update` выдает:

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install apility/laravel-fcm v1.4.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install apility/laravel-fcm v1.4.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install apility/laravel-fcm v1.4.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install apility/laravel-fcm v1.4.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - illuminate/support[v5.6.0, ..., v5.8.36] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., v6.19.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., v7.28.4] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires apility/laravel-fcm ^1.4 -> satisfiable by apility/laravel-fcm[1.4.0, ..., v1.4.4].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.2.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.3.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.3.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.4.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.4.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.5.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.5.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.6.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.7.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.8.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.8.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.9.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.10.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.10.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.11.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.12.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.12.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.12.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.13.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.14.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.14.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.15.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.16.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.17.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.18.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - apility/laravel-fcm 1.4.0 requires illuminate/support 5.*|^6|^7 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6].
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.17, v9.0.0, ..., v9.18.0], laravel/framework[v9.0.0, ..., v9.18.0]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.0.0, ..., v9.18.0].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Что ему нужно? Почему он просит PHP 7, если для обновления до Laravel 9 ему нужен PHP 8?

Если делаю `php composer.phar update` с параметрами

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.4",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
```

то все в порядке, обновлений никаких не находит и тесты все проходит.

Comment: а он поддерживает 8 пхп? Пишет же что _illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., v7.28.4] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement__

Comment: Laravel 9? Да, ему как раз-таки PHP 8 и нужен.

Comment: а `illuminate/support v.7` нужен 7-й. Надо еще зависимости отдельно обновить

Comment: попробуй убрать из конфига `"php": "^8.0",` пока не обновится

Comment: можно прислушаться к предложению композера использовать параметр --with-all-dependencies

Comment: Первоочередно, вам нужно глянуть на это: "laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it", значит, что они не могут присутствовать оба, либо то, либо это.